# FX Call under stochastic rates and deterministic volatility

Tags: black-scholes, call, pricing-formulae, fxo

Lets denote $S_t$, $r^d_t$,$r^f_t$ respectively the FX spot, the domestic rate and the foreign rate at time $t$.

Lets $\mathbb{Q}^d$ , $\mathbb{Q}^f$ respectively be the domestic and foreign mesures, and lets suppose that the rates follows Hull and white dynamics and that the FX spot follow a lognormal-like diffusion with constante volatility.

Hence we have the following equations :
$$dr_t^d=(a^d+\lambda_dr_t^d)dt+\sigma_ddW_t^d \text{ under }\mathbb{Q}^d$$
$$dr_t^f=(a^f+\lambda_fr_t^f)dt+\sigma_ddW_t^f \text{ under }\mathbb{Q}^f$$
$$ dS_t=(r^d_t-r^f_t)S_tdt+\sigma^{cst}S_tdW_t \text{ under }\mathbb{Q}^d$$

with $$dW_t^ddW_t^f=\rho_1dt$$
$$dW_t^ddW_t=\rho_2dt$$
$$dW_tdW_t^f=\rho_3dt$$

**Question**:
Is there a closed formula solution for the price of a currency call option under this system of equations ? I would like to study the impact of correlations on the price of the option and see how does it impact the closed formula for currency call option obtained under Black-scholes model.
One can notice the resemblance with the case of equity call option under black-scholes with stochastic interest rates already answered in a [previous post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/black-scholes-under-stochastic-interest-rates).

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Consider the call option with payoff $(S_T-K)^+$ at the option maturity $T$. Note that the forward exchange rate
\begin{align*}
F(t, T) = S_t \frac{P^f(t, T)}{P^d(t, T)}
\end{align*}
is a martingale under the domestic $T$-forward probability measure $Q^T$, where $P^d(T, T)$ and $P^f(T, T)$ are prices at time $t$ of respective domestic and foreign zero-coupon bonds with maturity $T$ and unit face values. As in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/black-scholes-under-stochastic-interest-rates), let
\begin{align*}
B_a(t, T) = \frac{1}{\lambda_a}\Big(e^{\lambda_a(T-t)}-1 \Big),
\end{align*}
for $a=d$ and $f$. Then, under $Q^T$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d F(t, T)}{F(t, T)} &= -\sigma_f B_f(t, T) dW_t^f + \sigma_d B_d(t, T) dW_t^d + \sigma^{cst} dW_t.
\end{align*}
Here, we use the same notations for the respective Brownian motions. Let $\sigma$ be a quantity defined by
\begin{align*}
T \sigma^2 &= \int_0^T\Big(\left(\sigma_f B_f(t, T)\right)^2 + \left(\sigma_d B_d(t, T)\right)^2 + (\sigma^{cst})^2 \\
&\qquad\qquad - 2 \sigma_d\sigma_f\rho_1 B_d(t, T)B_f(t, T) - 2 \rho_3 \sigma^{cst} \sigma_f B_f(t, T) + 2\rho_2 \sigma^{cst} \sigma_d B_d(t, T)\Big) dt.
\end{align*}
Then, the option value is given by
\begin{align*}
P^d(0, T)E_{Q^T}\left((F(T, T)-K)^+\right) &=P^d(0, T)\Big[F(0, T)N(d_1) - KN(d_2) \Big],
\end{align*}
where $d_1 = \frac{\ln F(0, T)/K + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$ and $d_2 = d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T}$.

Comment: How did you get the dynamics of the forward exchange rate under the forward rate ? not quite sure that $W_t^f$,$W_t^d$ and $W_t$ are brownien motions under $Q^T$

Comment: You first need to have the dynamics for $P^d(t, T)$,  $P^f(t, T)$, and $S_t$ under the domestic risk-neutral measure. Then, consider the dynamics under the $T$-forward measure. Note that, the measure change will change the drift, while I used the SAME notations for the Brownian motions. Given that the forward exchange rate is a martingale under the forward measure, we can ignore the drift terms and only consider the diffusion terms.

Comment: I can add more details for the measure changes later on.

Comment: yes I understand better now, Thanks.